# phabricator diffusion adding a bitbucket uri to observe repo outputs error

Tags: bitbucket, phabricator

I recently installed Phabricator to my personal server.

I am trying to observe my private bitbucket git repo, but I am getting following error.

`Unhandled Exception ("InvalidArgumentException")

Argument 1 passed to PhabricatorRepositoryURI::attachRepository() must be an instance of PhabricatorRepository, null given, called in /home/pi/phabricator/src/applications/diffusion/editor/DiffusionURIEditor.php on line 84 and defined`

I have created a new repo in Diffusion and went to the `Manage Repository` -> `URIs` menu and added bitbucket HTTPS URI in the form of `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git`.

Do I need additional settings? Can someone help?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update Phabricator.